# Cast image file to bytearray in SQL Server view?

Tags: sql-server

I want to load image from file into a SQL Server view based on column in that view.

Suppose that column is `a`, is it possible to use

```
cast('c:\image\'+ a +'.JPG' as varbinary(max))
```

Comment: Would that be a folder **on your SQL Server machine** ?? You cannot possibly want a remote SQL Server to access your own, local hard drive - or do you??

Comment: image folder is on SQL server machine

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\temp\mytxtfile.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) MyFile
```

or write your own function

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert using openrowset and bulkinsert as below:

```
create table yourimg (img varbinary(max))

insert into yourimg (img) 
select convert(varbinary(max), BulkColumn)  from openrowset(bulk N'C:\Users\test.png', single_blob) as a
```

in your case it has to be

```
select convert(varbinary(max), BulkColumn)  from openrowset(bulk N'C:\image\'+a+'.jpg', single_blob) as a
```

Comment: thank for your reply ,but i get error incorrect syntax near + despite using N in N'.jpg'